# angular 4 multiples reactive forms in tabs with one submit

Tags: forms, angular, reactive

I have a long entity, and we splitted the properties in a tab control, in different tabs.  But I need that when clicking the submit button (one on the form under all tabs) all the reactive forms validates.
What is the good way to get it?  Must I put all the forms in a formArray? Define one form with subforms?  And if so, can I put the forms in different tabs?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could create subforms, and since objects (which form is) are mutable in JS, your parent component (the one that holds the tab components) will be aware of any changes in going on in the children, so you can handle the validation from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to some shared service for holding data, and update data in each tab component. And when you will submit form, you get data from this service.
But it for very simple applications.

If you want a powerful service for storing immutable data and update data from each tab then you need use Redux technology.

See for general information about Redux http://redux.js.org/

And implementation Redux for Angular 4 https://github.com/ngrx/store